# Combination of Scrum and Kanban

Tags: agile, scrum, kanban

Is there a methodology where the process combines Scrum and Kanban and has both fixed sprint schedules and project backlog? I've heard of Scrumban and Kanplan but I'm not sure which is which.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because project-management is off-topic on SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kanban is a method to visualize and improve whatever you do currently. The Kanban Method encourages you to visualize your current process on a Kanban board, establish a pull mechanism to ensure team members take up new work when that actually have capacity, and improve the flow of work thru your process.

If you are currently doing Scrum and you apply Kanban on top of it to improve your team's performance, you are doing what is popularly called Scrumban.

Kanban helps Scrum teams identify and resolve bottlenecks in their current processes, using concepts such as WIP limits (to reduce multitasking) and classes of Service to deal with the variations in demand (the different types of work a software team usually does, such as new features, break-fixes, etc.) and make commitments to their product owners and other stakeholders based on their real capacity to deliver work.

In this process, Scrum teams may often move towards a 'sprint-less' delivery (just do releases on a regular cadence), while improving the frequency with which they deliver quality software. If they do so, many teams call that thenKanban process. However, that is not a necessary step at all. Team's can simply continue with Scrumban.

If you'd like to learn more about this, you can read up here - http://www.digite.com/Kanban-guide/what-is-scrumban

Hope this helps!